# How can I add space at the start of a line?

Tags: spacing, captions

I have this title below a figure in my paper:
[image]

How can I indent the second line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do please reveal which document class you employ.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want hanging indentation or simple centering of the lines below the caption's first line.

Comment: I have \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

Comment: I would like to add space before the second line

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you employ a LaTeX document class (such as the `article` class employed in the following sample code) that's compatible with the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, I can think of two ways to accomplish your formatting objective.

If the hanging indentation is supposed to apply from the left-hand edge of the caption, *including* the label "Figure" and associated number, I suggest you run

```
\captionsetup{format=plain,hangindent=5mm}
```

[image]

Conversely, if the hanging indentation is supposed to apply to just the caption text itself, I suggest you run

```
\captionsetup{format=hang,indention=5mm}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other class that's compatible with the caption package

\usepackage{caption}
%% uncomment one of the next two lines:
\captionsetup{format=plain,hangindent=5mm} 
%\captionsetup{format=hang,indention=5mm}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % filler text

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{\lipsum[1][1-3]} % three sentences of filler text
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed. Is there a character that represents spaces? Maybe I can just add a few spaces at the start of the second line.